# Cannot get audio to play in a Phaser 3 game

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm trying to learn how to put audio in a Phaser 3 game. Right now, my code can't even get passed preloading the audio:

```
    import Phaser from 'phaser'

const gameState = {
    playerSize: 50,
    playerSpeed: 400,
    playerHealth: 3,
    playerColor: 0x41E20E,
    enemies: []
}
export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene
{  


    preload()
    {
         //load sound effects
        this.load.audio('hit','/assets/sfx/hitSound.wav')
    }

    create()
    {   //create plater
        gameState.player = this.add.rectangle(300, 300, gameState.playerSize, gameState.playerSize, gameState.playerColor); 

        this.physics.add.existing(gameState.player)

        gameState.player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
        
        //create cursor keys
        gameState.cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        //create's the first enemy
        this.createEnemy();

        //Assign sfx
        gameState.sfx = {};
        gameState.sfx.hit = this.sound.add('hit')

    }
    update()
    {

        if (gameState.cursor.left.isDown)
        {
            gameState.player.body.velocity.x = -1*gameState.playerSpeed
        }
        else if
        (gameState.cursor.right.isDown)
        {
                gameState.player.body.velocity.x = gameState.playerSpeed
        }
        else
        { 
            gameState.player.body.velocity.x = 0
        }

        if (gameState.cursor.up.isDown){
            gameState.player.body.velocity.y = -1*gameState.playerSpeed
        }
        else if (gameState.cursor.down.isDown)
        {
            gameState.player.body.velocity.y = gameState.playerSpeed
        }
        else
        { 
            gameState.player.body.velocity.y = 0
        }
    }   
    
    createEnemy()
    {
        let enemy = this.add.circle(300,300,25,0xf00000)    
        this.physics.add.existing(enemy)
        enemy.body.collideWorldBounds = true
        enemy.body.velocity.x = 100
        enemy.body.velocity.y = 100
        enemy.body.bounce.x = 1
        enemy.body.bounce.y = 1
        this.physics.add.collider(gameState.player, enemy, ()=>{
            gameState.player.body.velocity.x = 0;
            gameState.player.body.velocity.x = 0;
            enemy.destroy()
        })
        gameState.enemies.push(enemy)

    }
}
```

I get the Error Message:

> ```
> phaser.js:123418 Error decoding audio: hit -  Unable to decode audio data
> (anonymous) @ phaser.js:123418
> phaser.js:106996 Uncaught Error: Audio key "hit" missing from cache
>     at new WebAudioSound (phaser.js:106996)
>     at WebAudioSoundManager.add (phaser.js:106577)
>     at GameScene.create (phaser.js:1)
>     at SceneManager.create (phaser.js:100720)
>     at SceneManager.loadComplete (phaser.js:100636)
>     at LoaderPlugin.emit (phaser.js:2218)
>     at LoaderPlugin.loadComplete (phaser.js:197141)
>     at LoaderPlugin.fileProcessComplete (phaser.js:197109)
>     at AudioFile.onProcessError (phaser.js:5321)
>     at AudioContext.<anonymous> (phaser.js:123419)
> WebAudioSound @ phaser.js:106996
> add @ phaser.js:106577
> create @ phaser.js:1
> create @ phaser.js:100720
> loadComplete @ phaser.js:100636
> emit @ phaser.js:2218
> loadComplete @ phaser.js:197141
> fileProcessComplete @ phaser.js:197109
> onProcessError @ phaser.js:5321
> (anonymous) @ phaser.js:123419
> localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
> ```

I'm a very new coder so I don't know if there is something silly that I'm missing. I've triple checked that the pathway and file name is correct. All the tutorials online make it look so easy.

Comment: Are you doing this locally or online. There seems to be a problem loading from heroku, check this link: https://phaser.discourse.group/t/error-audio-files-when-deploy-on-heroku/7092, hope it helps

Comment: You're trying to load the asset from '/assets/sfx/hitSound.wav', try going for 'assets/sfx/hitSound.wav'; in both cases check your Network tab to see if it's being fetched correctly. Also you might want to add some details on your setup/bundler to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to `preload`, you're loading `/assets/sfx/hitSound.wav`.
Just removing the first `/` should do the trick. But it dependes on your bundler configuration.

I've cleaned a bit your code, leaving here just the audio part.
As you can see it works properly.

```js
const gameState = {}

class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene
{  

    preload()
    {
         //load sound effects
        this.load.audio('working','https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav');

    }

    create()
    {
        //Assign sfx
        gameState.sfx = {};
        gameState.sfx.working = this.sound.add('working');
      
        let playWorkingButton = this.add.text(20, 20, 'PLAY WORKING', { fontSize: 30 });
        playWorkingButton.setInteractive();

        playWorkingButton.on('pointerdown', () => {
          gameState.sfx.working.play();
        });

    }

}

let game = new Phaser.Game({
 scene: GameScene
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.55.2/phaser.min.js"></script>

<div id="game"></div>
```